# javascript function to make sure string is in the format m/d/yyyy

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate a string against a regular expression and I have the JS code as below :

```
var regx = new RegExp("([1-9]|1[012])[- /.]([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d");

if (!regx.test(document.getElementById('toDate').value)) {
     alert('invalid from date format... ');
     return false;
}
```

I tried to test it with the value 7/4/2017 and it fails...

Do I have my regex wrong?...

Comment: My initial suggestion is to use a date parsing library instead of regex.

Comment: why does using regex fail here though.. i am using the same regex from a regular expression validator...

Comment: It definitely fails, the regex is invalid: https://regex101.com/r/Q1uyan/2

Comment: I would suggest using the `type="date"` attribute. it has visual representation from how the user wants to see the format but will always be a valid date in a iso standard

Comment: @psj01 it fails because you need to escape the backslashes in `\d` - it's interpreting that as a literal character *d*. You need `\\d`.

Comment: You should also note that your RegEx is very limited... it will only accept years ranging from 1900 to 2099. That might be okay for some situations, but it probably isn't best practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* write a regular expression that validates both the character format and the validity of the values as dates, but that's the hard way.

I recommend tackling the problem in two steps: format validation, followed by value validation.

Step 1. Validate `m/d/yyyy` format

The format is simple. 1 or 2 digits, a slash, 1 or 2 digits, another slash, and 4 digits.

```
/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/.test('1/4/2018')
//> true
```

Step 2: validate the string as a legitimate date

I think the simplest way to check if a string represents a valid date is to attempt to construct a `Date` based on it, and then check to see if the construction produces the results you expect.

```
var potentialDate = new Date(year, month, day)
```

Again, you can use a regex to extract the year, month, and day portions of the string.

```
var parts = string.match(/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/);
var potentialDate = new Date( parts[3] , parts[1] , parts[2] );
```

Or, if you value raw simplicity, you can just split on `'/'`, since you've already confirmed the basic format.

Finally, interrogate the date object to ensure that none of the constituent parts overflowed.

```
if( potentialDate.getFullYear() !== parseInt( parts[3] ) ) { /* error */ }
// etc.
```

This last step is needed because javascript permits this:

```
new Date(2018, 13, 1)
//> Tue Feb 05 2019 // month "13" has overflowed to push date into 2019
```

--

This is hard mode. Use something like momentjs or date-fns.

Comment: I agree with this. Validation via regex is either going to miss stuff or be unmaintainable. For example a valid date in OP's case would be the 31st of february or even `1/2.1900`. These are just some of the follies of using a regex in this case. Using `Date` can definitely work but it's indeed better to just use something like Moment or whatever that can just take a string and extract the date, so you don't have to manually do it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to do it this way u suggested.

Comment: FWIW: olleicua's regex approach has the tech right. But, as a lover of regular expressions (I even have a regex app in the App Store), I have learned that vlaz's point about maintainability is a wise one. Relying on a single regex to enforce many business rules is a surefire way to produce regexes that are "write-only" -- they are extremely difficult for future maintainers to read, and are very difficult to document in code.

Comment: momentjs is the real answer see discussion of why the regexp failed below

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using the `RegeExp` constructor you will need to use double slashes escape the numeric matches so `\\d` instead of `\d`.

If you want to instead use RegExp literal syntax you could but you would need to escape the forward slashes. Also it's generally a good idea to escape dashes inside square brackets.

This should work: `/([1-9]|1[012])[\- \/.]([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\- \/.](19|20)\d\d/`

https://regex101.com/ is really helpful for this sort of thing.

Here is a link to your regex already input into regex101.com
https://regex101.com/r/Q1uyan/1

notice that when you don't escape the forward slashes it gives an error

Comment: That is wrong, though - forward slashes are reported as problem on regex101 because it assumes you are using a regex literal, e.g., `/slash//` - THAT is a problem. In this case it's because the *backslashes* are not escaped, namely the `\d` is in a string, so it's interpreted as an escaped `d` character...in other words a valid date would be `7/4/20dd`